# java.util.Stack collision with Own stack class in java

Tags: java, collections, stack

Can anyone gimme an example on this quote,

"If you want to use Stack class in your own code, you will need to fully specify the package or change the name of the class -when you create one; otherwise you will probably collide with the stack in java.util.package"

its from "thinking in java"...i tried to have an example that collides with java.util stack class with own stack class. everything is working fine for me..Can anyone gimme the collision example.

Comment: Post the code you wrote.

Comment: They might be talking about how if you have two classes with the same name you will need to use the fully qualified name to distinguish them

Comment: Yeah, they're simply saying that if you have your own Stack class and then `import java.util.*` then there will be a name collision.  This is no different from any other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a `Stack.java` class file in your package ( say `com.example.app` ) as:

```
public class Stack{}
```

Then from another file `main` if you want to use both the `java.util.Stack` and your own class you will have an ambiguous reference error in the imports or in usage:

```
import java.util.Stack;
import com.example.app.Stack;

public class Main{

    Stack stack;
}
```

If you actually want to use both of them in your `main` file you can resolve the ambiguity as:

```
java.util.Stack javaStack;
com.example.app.Stack myStack;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the book is trying to draw a distinction involving three classes `java.util.Stack`, `my.pack.Stack` and (for this example) `my.pack.Fred` with three `Stack`s in the `Fred` class,

```
package my.pack;
// import java.util.Stack; // <-- a collision...

public class Fred {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    my.pack.Stack<?> myStack = new my.pack.Stack<>();
    java.util.Stack<?> utilStack = new java.util.Stack<>();
    Stack<?> collision = new Stack<>(); // <-- The collision.
  }
}
```